# How to render an complex Object with nested Objects and arrays inside in React/JSX

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, object, jsx

I get this Object as a response from an API:

```
{
  "transcript": {
    "monologues": [
      {
        "speaker": 0,
        "elements": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "value": "Bobby",
            "ts": 2.99,
            "end_ts": 3.55,
            "confidence": 0.82
          },
          { "type": "punct", "value": " " },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "value": "tell",
            "ts": 6.99,
            "end_ts": 7.47,
            "confidence": 0.74
          },
          { "type": "punct", "value": " " },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "value": "them",
            "ts": 7.47,
            "end_ts": 7.63,
            "confidence": 0.44
          },
          { "type": "punct", "value": "." }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do i get `"speaker"` and `"value"` from the `"elements"` array?

I tried to map through the "monologues" array and then nest another map of the "elements" array like this:

```
{transcription.transcript?.monologues.map((monologue, i) => {
  return monologue.elements.map((text, i) => {
    return <p>{text.value}</p>;
  });
})}
```

but for some reason it's not working. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that somewhere in my code i was stringifying the json response and i had to parse it back:

```
{JSON.parse(transcription).transcript?.monologues.map((monologue, i) => {
  return monologue.elements.map((text, i) => {
    return <p>{text.value}</p>;
  });
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting a `map()` within a `map()`. This would result in a structure which has an array within an array.

Using your example, your end result would be something like:

```
[["bobby", " ", "tell", " ", "."], [/* Other monologues here if there were any*/]]
```

What you probably want is a flat array of the values so the [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) function is your best friend.

This should be better:

```
{transcription.transcript?.monologues.flatMap((monologue, i) => {
  return monologue.elements.map((text, i) => {
    return <p>{text.value}</p>;
  });
})}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code so may have to tweak it a bit if it doesn't work as is.

Comment: In fact my code was working fine i just had a mistake somewhere else. Check my answer below.